# Can I add comments to each entries in crontab after a crontab entry

Tags: cron

We have bunch of crontab entries in crontab file. some of them are commented out temporarily. Is it possible to add a comment at the entry as the reason for commenting out.

For example

```
#00 20 * * *  sh test.sh  "Adding comments here, reason for commenting out"
```

Answer (score 17):

While comments are probably more readable on a line of their own:

```
## This is commented out because the frobication goes foobar /ilkkachu 2020-11-01
# 00 20 * * *  sh test.sh
```

you should also be able to put comments after the command:

```
00 20 * * *  sh test.sh  # frobnicate the sales data
```

This should work because the shell considers `#` as starting a comment, and while `cron` passes it the whole line after the time fields, the shell ignores the part starting with a `#`.

Comment: Comments on the same line are specifically not allowed: https://serverfault.com/questions/183399/can-you-have-a-multi-line-comment-a-crontab#comment1301593_183401

Comment: @JoshM., yes, cron passes the comment in that second block to the shell as part of the command line, and the _shell_ then treats it as a comment and ignores it.

Comment: See my question [Why are comments in the same crontab line as the crontab job are not allowed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749963).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to have a clear syntax, every comment in its own line(s), above the command that is commenting.

```bsh
# comment this is doing that
0 0 * * *     command
# Uncomment this line to do this. Comment line if that. The reason is this.
#0 0 1 * *     command
# comment text
0 0 1 * *     command
```

If your comment is (short and) explanatory enough, there is no reason to modify it, depending on when the following command is commented or not.

Your example line also works, as the whole line is a comment. If you uncomment the beginning, the trailing comment is still a comment, not for crontab, but for the command to execute, so it is expected to work. Another readability issue is trailing comments result to long lines.

Also have a look at man `crontab(5)`:

> Blank lines, leading spaces, and tabs are ignored.  Lines whose first
> non-white space character is a
> pound-sign (#) are comments, and are not processed.  Note that comments are not allowed on the  same
> line as cron commands, since they are considered a part of the command.  Similarly, comments are not
> allowed on the same line as environment variable settings.