# Why are comments in the same crontab line as the crontab job are not allowed?

Tags: cron

It might depend on my none native English but the [crontab.5](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) manpage contradicts itself.

> Blank lines and leading spaces and tabs are ignored. Lines whose first
> non-space character is a pound-sign (#) are comments, and are ignored.
> Note that comments are not allowed on the same line as cron commands,
> since they will be taken to be part of the command. Similarly,
> comments are not allowed on the same line as environment variable
> settings.

A crontab line for example

```
00 20 * * *  sh test.sh  # frobnicate the sales data
```

This seems to work. So where is the problem?

It is clear to me that this comment is not parsed and interpreted by cron itself. It is treated as part of the last command field and handed over to the shell. The shell treat it as a comment without problems.

So where is the problem?

Or is the crontab manpage just not well formulated?

Comment: check the command line arguments your test.sh receives

Comment: @JaromandaX, it will get no arguments.

Comment: @ilkkachu - d'oh, of course it won't :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, ...the hash sign will be there when cron runs a shell and gives it the command from the crontab. Just that that shell will remove the comment as part of parsing the command, before running `sh` to interpret `test.sh`...

Comment: "Why" something in a language is so usually a pointless question - someone could always come up with a variation of that language that doesn't have a given limitation. For example, a command list inside braces in bash must be terminated by a newline or other command terminator like `;` or `&`, so you can't have `foo () { echo bar }` in bash, but it is perfectly valid to do so in zsh. _Why_ not in bash? Because either nobody bothered to implement the zsh variation in bash, or the people who maintain bash don't feel it's worth adding it. ¯\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

Answer (score 3):

Like Marcus's answer says, you've already answered your question here:

> It is clear to me that this comment is not parsed and interpreted by cron itself. It is treated as part of the last command field and handed over to the shell. The shell treat it as a comment without problems.

But to put that into some practical context, consider the following:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
* * * * * foo.sh bar#bar
```

that runs `/bin/sh` with the arguments `-c` and `foo.sh bar#bar`, where a POSIX-like sh shouldn't take the `#` as a comment marker, but runs `foo.sh` with the argument `bar#bar`. Cron didn't care about the "comment".

```
* * * * * foo.sh "foo #bar"
```

Similar to the previous.

```
SHELL=/bin/echo
* * * * * foo bar # asdf
```

That runs `echo` with the arguments `-c` and `foo bar # asdf`. `echo` duly prints the string. Cron didn't care about the "comment".

In the simpler case you had there,

```
00 20 * * *  sh test.sh  # frobnicate the sales data
```

cron runs a shell with the arguments `-c` and `sh test.sh  # frobnicate the sales data`, and there, a POSIX-like shell should treat that as a comment and remove it before running `sh test.sh`. It's just that cron doesn't really care what the "shell" does with the command line.

The man page saying "comments are not allowed" does not mean you're forbidden from putting hash signs there, just that they're not treated as comments by cron. "Allow" here means "to make possible" (see e.g. [Wiktionary, sense 7](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/allow)).

Comment: I assume I do understand that. I see no problem about it that the comment is handed over to the shell. If there is no problem then why shouldn't it be allowed? The crontab manpage could just state that it do not handle and interpret such comments. It shouldn't say that it is not allowed. My decision using such comments or not will affect multiple 10k of people using my software. That is why I am so serious about it.

Comment: @buhtz it's incredibly hard to understand what you're confused about. The string `#bar` **is not a comment** in this context. You did not write a comment on the line.

Comment: @buhtz, e.g. [Wiktionary lists "To render physically possible." as one meaning of the word "allow"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/allow), and that's the applicable sense here. "Comments are not allowed" == "Comments are not possible". But if you're worried, the safe option is of course always not to put such comments in the command.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, from Cron's perspective, it is not considered a comment.

This indeed answers the question:

There are no Cron comments possible in these lines; the entire remaining part of the line is copied as a command to be executed by a shell. How the shell invoked by Cron handles that string is solely the shell's responsibility, and your `#` symbol may not be interpreted as a comment in the chosen shell.

The man page provides precise information on this matter, so I find it to be well-formulated. In fact, it even explains the consequences if one attempts to place a comment there.

As for the "**why**", there is no specific answer. It is defined the way it is defined.

Comment: I can't accept this as an answer. When it is "not allowed" there must be a reason. I assume it can cause a problem. But I can't find one.

Comment: @buhtz, you're reading too much into it.

Comment: no, there does not have to be a reason; that's simply not the case. When I write a program that works one way, that's how I wrote it. When that program becomes kind of a standard, the way it works becomes the rule of how it works. There's still no reason.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is if it can create any problem using a comment on the same line as the crontab-job line.

Comment: you can't, because there's no comments on these lines. Exactly as you noticed the man page says – all the things are passed to the shell. Now that you're aware of that, there can't be a problem, because you know what you write on that line will be passed to the shell.

Comment: @buhtz, that "allowed" there only means cron doesn't recognize or treat a hash sign there as a comment, but as a regular character. It doesn't _forbid_ you from putting hash signs there, just says that any such will be passed along to the command (shell) that runs. You just need to be aware of that to know what the hash signs will do in the shell. And not e.g. assume cron will remove them.